# insert with one to many relation spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

What i have is single page to get all the fields with its relations data.

What i want to achieve is insert Package and then insert its related iteneraries at the same time.

How do I do this? Please comment if any thing is missing that I must add to the question.

display form controller

```
@GetMapping("/add-tour-package")
public String showAddPackageForm(Model model) {
    TourPackage tourPackage = new TourPackage();
    Itinerary itinerary = new Itinerary();
    model.addAttribute("tourPackage", tourPackage);
    model.addAttribute("itinerary", itinerary);
    return "new-tour-package";
}
```

Insert Tour package

```
@PostMapping("/save-tour-package")
public String saveTourPackage(@ModelAttribute("tourPackage") TourPackage tourPackage, @ModelAttribute("itinerary") Itinerary itinerary) {
    // save package to database
    tourPackageService.saveTourPackage(tourPackage);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

form with dynamic fields. Note that itinerary is dynamic input fields so there will be multiple itinerary.

```
<form th:action="@{/save-tour-package}" th:object="${tourPackage}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" th:field="*{title}" placeholder="Title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" th:field="*{description}"
                          placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="geography">Geography</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="geography" th:field="*{geography}"
                               placeholder="Geography">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="location">Location</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" th:field="*{location}"
                               placeholder="Location">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="difficulty">Difficulty</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="difficulty" th:field="*{difficulty}"
                               placeholder="Difficulty">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="altitude">Altitude</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="altitude" th:field="*{altitude}"
                               placeholder="Altitude">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="religion">Religion</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="religion" th:field="*{religion}"
                               placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ethnic_people">Ethnic People</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ethnic_people" th:field="*{ethnic_people}"
                               placeholder="Ethnic People">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="accommodation">Accommodation</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accommodation" th:field="*{accommodation}"
                               placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="transportation">Transportation</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transportation" th:field="*{transportation}"
                               placeholder="Transportation">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="minimum_pax">Minimum Pax</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="minimum_pax" th:field="*{minimum_pax}"
                               placeholder="Minimum Pax">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price">Price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" th:field="*{price}" placeholder="Price">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row append-new-field">
                <div class="col-2">Day</div>
                <div class="col-3">Title</div>
                <div class="col-3">Description</div>
                <div class="col-3">Altitude</div>
                <div class="col-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row delete-field">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="${itinerary.day}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="${itinerary.title}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="${itinerary.description}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="${itinerary.altitude}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="text-danger delete-row"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="addItineraryFields()" class="text-success">Add Fields</a>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save Tour Package</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Itinerary model

```
package com.pristine.travels.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "itinerary")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Itinerary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private long id;
    private String day;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String altitude;
    private String duration;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date added_date;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date update_date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="packages_id")
    private TourPackage packages;

    public Itinerary() {
    }

    public Itinerary(long id, String day, String title, String description, String altitude, String duration, Date added_date, Date update_date, TourPackage packages) {
        this.id = id;
        this.day = day;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.added_date = added_date;
        this.update_date = update_date;
        this.packages = packages;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }

    public void setAltitude(String altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Date getAdded_date() {
        return added_date;
    }

    public void setAdded_date(Date added_date) {
        this.added_date = added_date;
    }

    public Date getUpdate_date() {
        return update_date;
    }

    public void setUpdate_date(Date update_date) {
        this.update_date = update_date;
    }

    public TourPackage getPackages() {
        return packages;
    }

    public void setPackages(TourPackage packages) {
        this.packages = packages;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Itinerary{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", day='" + day + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", altitude='" + altitude + '\'' +
                ", duration='" + duration + '\'' +
                ", added_date=" + added_date +
                ", update_date=" + update_date +
                ", packages=" + packages +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Itinerary itinerary = (Itinerary) o;
        return id == itinerary.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Tour package model

```
package com.pristine.travels.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tour_package")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TourPackage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String geography;
    private String location;
    private String difficulty;
    private String altitude;
    private String religion;
    private String ethnic_people;
    private String accommodation;
    private String transportation;
    private String minimum_pax;
    private Integer price;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date added_date;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date update_date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "packages")
    private Set<Itinerary> itineraries;

    public TourPackage() {
    }

    public TourPackage(long id, String title, String description, String geography, String location, String difficulty, String altitude, String religion, String ethnic_people, String accommodation, String transportation, String minimum_pax, Integer price, Date added_date, Date update_date, Set<Itinerary> itineraries) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.geography = geography;
        this.location = location;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.religion = religion;
        this.ethnic_people = ethnic_people;
        this.accommodation = accommodation;
        this.transportation = transportation;
        this.minimum_pax = minimum_pax;
        this.price = price;
        this.added_date = added_date;
        this.update_date = update_date;
        this.itineraries = itineraries;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getGeography() {
        return geography;
    }

    public void setGeography(String geography) {
        this.geography = geography;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(String difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public String getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }

    public void setAltitude(String altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }

    public String getReligion() {
        return religion;
    }

    public void setReligion(String religion) {
        this.religion = religion;
    }

    public String getEthnic_people() {
        return ethnic_people;
    }

    public void setEthnic_people(String ethnic_people) {
        this.ethnic_people = ethnic_people;
    }

    public String getAccommodation() {
        return accommodation;
    }

    public void setAccommodation(String accommodation) {
        this.accommodation = accommodation;
    }

    public String getTransportation() {
        return transportation;
    }

    public void setTransportation(String transportation) {
        this.transportation = transportation;
    }

    public String getMinimum_pax() {
        return minimum_pax;
    }

    public void setMinimum_pax(String minimum_pax) {
        this.minimum_pax = minimum_pax;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Date getAdded_date() {
        return added_date;
    }

    public void setAdded_date(Date added_date) {
        this.added_date = added_date;
    }

    public Date getUpdate_date() {
        return update_date;
    }

    public void setUpdate_date(Date update_date) {
        this.update_date = update_date;
    }

    public Set<Itinerary> getItineraries() {
        return itineraries;
    }

    public void setItineraries(Set<Itinerary> itineraries) {
        this.itineraries = itineraries;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TourPackage{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description=" + description +
                ", geography='" + geography + '\'' +
                ", location='" + location + '\'' +
                ", difficulty='" + difficulty + '\'' +
                ", altitude='" + altitude + '\'' +
                ", religion='" + religion + '\'' +
                ", ethnic_people='" + ethnic_people + '\'' +
                ", accommodation='" + accommodation + '\'' +
                ", transportation='" + transportation + '\'' +
                ", minimum_pax='" + minimum_pax + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", added_date=" + added_date +
                ", update_date=" + update_date +
                ", itineraries=" + itineraries +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TourPackage that = (TourPackage) o;
        return id == that.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

TourPackage save function

```
@Override
public long saveTourPackage(TourPackage tourPackage) {
    this.tourPackagesRepo.save(tourPackage);
    return 0;
}
```

Itinerary save function

```
@Override
public long saveItinerary(Itinerary itinerary) {
    this.itineraryRepo.save(itinerary);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before doing `tourPackageService.saveTourPackage(tourPackage);` just set Itineraries for that tourPackage: `tourPackage.setItineraries(itinerary);`. Make sure you do the same for Itineraries (before `tourPackage.setItineraries(itinerary);`):

> itinerary.forEach(item -> { item.setTourPackage(tourPackage); }

then do tourPackageService.saveTourPackage(tourPackage);

Comment: can you be more specific, it throws error when I try what you have suggested @White Link

Comment: What is the error? can i see your saveTourPackage() function? did you setTourPackage for itinerary as well?

Comment: by what you are saying is this correct `public String saveTourPackage(@ModelAttribute("tourPackage") TourPackage tourPackage, @ModelAttribute("itinerary") Itinerary itinerary)`

Comment: Error:(44, 18) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method forEach((item)->{ [...]e); })
  location: variable itinerary

Comment: Base on what you said:' form with dynamic fields. Note that itinerary is dynamic input fields so there will be multiple itinerary'. It should be @ModelAttribute("itinerary") Set<Itinerary> itinerary or the like